# Calculate two equal teams with player rating

Tags: javascript, algorithm, partitioning

I often play a game where every player has a rating. For example 1678 or 1820. When you win a game you get points, when you loose, you lose points.

Now, when 8 players join a lobby we want to have equal teams (4v4), or as close as possible, rating wise. There are always 2 teams and players from 3 to 8 (can be uneven teams too like 2v1).

What algorithm can I use to create two equal teams in JavaScript?

For example:

```
ratings = [1466, 1678, 1988, 1200, 1362, 1555, 1844, 1600];

team 1: [xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx] ??
team 2: [xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx] ??
```

Comment: Find all combinations and choose the most balanced one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first sort it and then add to first or second array based on sum of each one.

```js
function distribute(arr) {
  arr.sort().reverse()
  let a = [], b = [], sumA = 0, sumB = 0, i = 0

  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (!sumA && !sumB || sumA == sumB) {
      a.push(arr[i])
      sumA += arr[i]
    } else if (sumA < sumB) {
      a.push(arr[i])
      sumA += arr[i];
    } else if (sumB < sumA) {
      b.push(arr[i])
      sumB += arr[i];
    }
    i++
  }
  
  console.log(`Total: ${sumA} ${sumB}`)
  return [a, b]
}

console.log(distribute([1466, 1678, 1988, 1200, 1362, 1555, 1844, 1600]))
console.log(distribute([1466, 6000, 1988, 1200, 1362, 1555, 1844, 1600]))
```

Comment: Beauty! Works great.

Comment: Quick greedy algorithm but suboptimal. Also, it always uses all of the players.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked in javascript, but maybe it can be helpful for you.
All i did is got average value of the array(sum of all values and / to the number of teams, in my case it's 2 teams) =>
 sorted array => 
pushed values to team1 array till the the sum of the team1 array > then average value =>
rest pushed to the team2 array

```
    ratings = [1306, 1578, 1458, 1450,1602, 1355, 1454, 1300]
    from functools import reduce
    class match_making(object):
        team1 = []
        team2 = []
        def __init__(self,ratings): 
            self.ratings = ratings
        def get_value(self):
            self.average_value = reduce(lambda x,y: x + y / 2 ,self.ratings)
        def split_players (self):
            x = 0
            for player in sorted(self.ratings):
                x = x + player
                if x < self.average_value:
                    self.team1.append(player)
                    print(x)
                elif x > self.average_value:
                    self.team2.append(player)

        def dowork(self):
            self.get_value()
            self.split_players()
            some = reduce(lambda x , y :x +y , self.team1) #just too see average rating of the team1
            some2 = reduce(lambda x , y :x +y , self.team2)# same as above for team2
            return some,some2,self.team1,self.team2


    divide_players = match_making(ratings)
    print(divide_players.dowork())
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited it to make it a little more concise and moved the compare outside for clarity. But this does basic distribution of players after sorting by rank.

```js
let ratings = [1466, 1678, 1988, 1200, 1362, 1555, 1844, 1600];

let team1 = [];
let team2 = []; 

const sortNumber = (n1, n2) => {
  if(n1 > n2) return -1;
  if(n1 < n2) return 1;
  return 0;
};


// Simple distibution
function distributePlayers(arrPlayers) {

  let sortedPlayers = arrPlayers.sort(sortNumber);
  console.log(sortedPlayers);
  let teams = [[],[]];
  
  sortedPlayers.forEach((player, index) => {
      teams[index%2].push(player);
  });
  
  return teams;
}

distributePlayers(ratings).forEach(team => {
  console.log(team);
});
```

Here is a basic sort and distribute.

```js
let ratings = [1466, 1678, 1988, 1200, 1362, 1555, 1844, 1600];

let team1 = [];
let team2 = []; 


// Simple distibution
function distributePlayers(arrPlayers) {
  let sortedPlayers = arrPlayers.sort((p1, p2) => {
    if(parseInt(p1) > parseInt(p2)) {
      return -1;
    } else if (parseInt(p1) < parseInt(p2)) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  console.log(sortedPlayers);
  let teams = [[],[]];
  
  sortedPlayers.forEach((player, index) => {
      let teamIndex = index%2;
      teams[(teamIndex)].push(player);
  });
  
  return teams;
}

distributePlayers(ratings).forEach(team => {
  console.log(team);
})
```

Comment: Note, this just sorts and round robin distributes. If you wanted to get clever you might want to weight their skill level based on the mean of the group and balance that way.

Comment: When I use your script with the array [1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100]. I get: [2100, 1900, 1700, 1500] (total 7200) vs [2000, 1800, 1600, 1400] (total 6800). Which isnt the perfect balance.
The perfect balance for example is [1400, 2100, 1500, 2000] vs [1600, 1700, 1800, 1900] (both teams have 7000 points)

Comment: Yes, I agree. But as a gamer we also know that a player with 6000 does not equal 3 players at 2000. Hence the need to weight their rank rather than purely add.

Comment: By that I mean we would need to divide rank by opposing team distribution.